# Marker-end do not work

Tags: html, css, dom, svg

I encounter a problem with my `marker-end`.

I try to display an arrow but it doesn't work. When I directly change the SVG line in the HTML code, the arrow appears.

[image: Before]
[image: After]

When I change my code it doesn't work. To see the arrow appear I have to directly change the code in the source code of the page.
Someone know why? And how to fix this?

For example here I have just changed the width manually to make it work...

[image: ???]

```
path.SVGEdgeView{
    stroke: #777 !important ;
    stroke-width: 1.5px !important ;
    marker-end: url(#arrow-edge-end-marker) !important ;
}

<path class="SVGEdgeView" id="0.2916158037260175" d="M1290 80C1365 80 1515 205 1440 205"></path>
```

Comment: I don't see any place where you set marker end style, can you post also your not working code? (please code, not screenshots)

Comment: I would put a minimal testing example on a jsfiddle.

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: Show us *all* of your code. A pscreenshot of your code is not helpful.  Please make a code snippet or jsfiddle or something so we can see it failing for ourselves.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

I had created my svg with document.createElement(tagname) instead of document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tagname).

The svg element was not well created.